# Convert Long Value to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using Formating function to format Date,most of the values come in DateTime Format which are sent to this function for Formating but sometimes i get values like `40544` in data which is a Long Value,Because of this i get DateTime Exception so I want to convert it into datatime.
When i paste this in Excel and format it to date it gives me `1/1/2011`.How can i get same in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: I want C# function to convert long value to DateTime e.g. 40544 to 1/1/2011,there is no need for posting any code....

Comment: I agree with Sam, the question is not so clear, "I am using Formating function..." are you already using one? which one? the long values where are coming from? what kind of encoding? unix epoch? excel ?

Comment: After copy pating above value in excel and format that cell to Date,it will give 1/1/2011 value

Comment: Looking to this further the value is NOT a long value it has to be a OLE Automation Date `double` value to make any sense. Which means using `DateTime FromOADate(double d)` is what you want to use.

Comment: No that formating function is different written by our team...sorry for bad english...or not properly using wordings....however problem is solved now...thanks you guys..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`DateTime.FromOADate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) but it is hard to say as your question is kind of vague.

Comment: Thank you very work...it worked :)

Comment: This is the only answer that makes any sense ( except perhaps Oliver's answer ) based on the information the author provide.  Good Work!

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I've done some work importing data from Excel before so it kind of rang a bell.

Answer (score 4):

It's the number of days since the 1st January 1900.

So simply try the following:

```
var number = 40544;
var date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(number);
```

Comment: I assume you meant "since"?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Absolutely. Fixed it.